# Date from date picker not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am reading data from a date picker, saving it locally and then setting a label to the value of the date set, but the label is blank! Please help!

The code to save the data:

```
NSDate *valueToSave5 = [testday date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave5 forKey:@"t1TestDay"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And then to load it:

```
NSString *t1TestDay = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"t1TestDay"];
```

And finally to set the label:

```
_TestDayValue.text = t1TestDay;
```

Comment: post some code jack!

Comment: NSDate is no NSString, check available methods to get a formatted string from a NSDate object to save and retrieve it

Comment: I don't understand - I'm still very new to this

Comment: what you are trying to say? Your want to save  [testday date] into _TestDayValue.text or you want to convert your data into date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saved an NSDate object to NSUserDefaults, so you should load it back with that same type.

Try this to load NSDate back:

```
 NSDate *t1TestDay = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"t1TestDay"];
```

And to display it in the label, you have to convert NSDate to NSString in some way, e.g., using NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; // 27/02/2017

NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate: t1TestDay];
_TestDayValue.text = stringFromDate;
```

*Note: the code is not tested.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code which work for you.

```
    NSDate *valueToSave5 = [NSDate date];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave5 forKey:@"t1TestDay"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSDate *t1TestDay = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"t1TestDay"];
    NSLog(@"%@",t1TestDay.description);
```

You are stored **NSDate** as **Object** into NSUserDefaults. But when you try to get as **String**. So you need to get value as you stored.

Answer (score -1):

you will try

```
NSDate *valueToSave5 = [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave5                                              forKey:@"t1TestDay"];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"t1TestDay"]);
```